# Coordinate Reference Systems error CRSAuthorityFactory

Tags: coordinate-system, java, geotools

When I try to set CRS in geotools application first time it works great but after that I get FactoryNotFoundException
it shows me this in console

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.geotools.factory.FactoryNotFoundException: No factory of kind "CRSAuthorityFactory" found.
    at org.geotools.swing.dialog.CRSListModel.<init>(CRSListModel.java:87)
    at org.geotools.swing.dialog.JCRSChooser$CRSDialog.createControlPanel(JCRSChooser.java:248)
    at org.geotools.swing.dialog.AbstractSimpleDialog.initComponents(AbstractSimpleDialog.java:137)
    at org.geotools.swing.dialog.JCRSChooser$CRSDialog.<init>(JCRSChooser.java:241)
    at org.geotools.swing.dialog.JCRSChooser.doShow(JCRSChooser.java:202)
    at org.geotools.swing.dialog.JCRSChooser.showDialog(JCRSChooser.java:154)
    at org.geotools.swing.menu.JCRSPopupMenu.setCRS(JCRSPopupMenu.java:137)
    at org.geotools.swing.menu.JCRSPopupMenu.access$000(JCRSPopupMenu.java:50)
    at org.geotools.swing.menu.JCRSPopupMenu$1.actionPerformed(JCRSPopupMenu.java:81)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.geotools.factory.FactoryNotFoundException: No factory of kind "CRSAuthorityFactory" found.
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProvider(FactoryRegistry.java:375)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.getServiceProvider(FactoryCreator.java:145)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getAuthorityFactory(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:220)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactory(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:440)
    at org.geotools.swing.dialog.CRSListModel.<init>(CRSListModel.java:71)
    ... 46 more
```

at first I thought that this is something because my code but I get the same exception in all apps I have(Quickstart). If I export shapefile with geotools app, and run it again I get this exception at first try to set CRS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-4463) but is now fixed.